# List of youtube videos in my app

Tags: iphone, ios, youtube-api

I want to do one application in which i want to get the list of YouTube videos in one `UITableView`.So how to get that list of YouTube videos. Is there any api for YouTube information.

Answer (score 0):

Google "youtube api"

[First reference Link !](https://developers.google.com/youtube/)

Answer (score 0):

```
  follow Youtube API
   https://developers.google.com/youtube/

   You can use PSYouTubeExtractor.h class It can get youtube mp4 video url and than downloading and viewing is not a problem

  Here is my example https://github.com/comonitos/youtube_video
```